# current-menu-item class in CSS

Tags: menus, css

I have created one main Page(**Home Page**) and many custom links in wp-admin. All custom links are linked to sections of Home Page.

Example: Custom link **About Us** has a URL = #section1 and in my code I have linked it to:

`<div id="section1"> Text </div>`

In my CSS I have used **.current-menu-item** to highlight clicked link in menu:

```
.site-header div.nav-wrap nav ul li.current-menu-item a:link,
.site-header div.nav-wrap nav ul li.current-menu-item a:visited {

color: #fff;
text-shadow: -1px 1px 8px #ffc, 1px -1px 8px #fff;

}
```

When I jump to section1 only the **Home Page** link highlights not the **About Us** link. How can I fix this so that the **About us** Link highlights?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use different styling for active menu items on a single page website or automatically select correct menu items you should use a jQuery plugin like [this one](https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav).